# in c++, after reading in a file using a terminal window how can i use standard input?

Tags: c++, input

I have a program where I read in a data file to populate a list of information

(`./myProgram < dataFile.dat`)

After the file is read i am unable to get standard input (cin) in that terminal window to work, it does not ever give the chance to enter input, but simply skips over it most likely grabbing some random value to be stored in.  Is there any way to utilize cin after reading in a file as listed above?

Comment: How are you populating the list of information? Are you utilizing ifstream to read the data file, and then do you store the values to a string, or array which can be printed out using iostream?

Comment: Do you want to post some source to go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your shell environment, you can feed the file into another fd than stdin:

```
$ cat fd_in.c 
int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[1024];
    int bytesread;

    bytesread = read(3,buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("file is %d bytes\n",bytesread);

    bytesread = read(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("you entered %d bytes\n",bytesread);
}
$ gcc fd_in.c
$ ./a.out 3< fd_in.c 
file is 220 bytes
my input!
you entered 10 bytes
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the 3< do?

Comment: It redirects the file to file descriptor 3, which you can see is being explicitly read from in the first `read` in `main`.

Comment: exactly, and likewise you can redirect multiple output streams using `3>`, `4>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`./myProgram < dataFile.dat` means that standard input will be sourced from `dataFile.dat`, not from the keyboard. So if you run the program like this, you will not be able read keyboard data from standard input. While standard input/output are easy to use and make the program amenable to piping, etc. they work most naturally when your program has a single input and/or a single output. If your input comes from two different sources, as seems to be the case for you, then you should make your program explicitly open the file and read from it, using an `ifstream`. That way, keyboard input will still be available from `cin`.

On a separate note, it is a good idea to check if your reads succeed. If you had done so, you would have seen that all your reads from `cin` after the file is done are failing due to the end of file being reached.

Comment: This is not generally true. A good example is `openssl` which allows you to specify which fd you use to feed it various pieces of data. This allows you to run `openssl` without having to write all kinds of temporary files to disk or put all data on the command line.

Comment: That is good to know, but I think it is overkill in this situation. Also, what part of what I said isn't generally true?

Comment: The "should" in *If your input comes from two different sources, as seems to be the case for you, then you should make your program explicitly open the file and read from it*.